# Plot Polygons with Carto

Tags: maps, cartodb

I have the following data file, where each row have a coordinate file:
id - identifies the polygon
barrio - you can ignore(is the name of the place)
volume - the scale that will be the color of the polyhon
long - longitude
lat - latitude

```
0   Pueblo Nuevo    32721.5 -3.6449779397   40.4307339003
0   Pueblo Nuevo    32721.5 -3.64510182294  40.4307061424
0   Pueblo Nuevo    32721.5 -3.64534323472  40.4306011803
0   Pueblo Nuevo    32721.5 -3.64558445341  40.4304737628
0   Pueblo Nuevo    32721.5 -3.64582154951  40.4303417733
0   Pueblo Nuevo    32721.5 -3.64594391235  40.4302735093
1   Palacio 24301.5 -3.71015464172  40.4229425859
1   Palacio 24301.5 -3.7102954769   40.4228156123
1   Palacio 24301.5 -3.71057024411  40.4225706548
1   Palacio 24301.5 -3.71060800746  40.422516382
1   Palacio 24301.5 -3.71066930547  40.4224934781
```

Using Carto, is it possible to plot the 2 polygons (similar to this: http://sensitivecities.com/images/london_plaque_density.png)? 
I tried to do with analysis/group polygons but it looks strange. Also there is superposition of the vertices.

[image]

Comment: Can you elaborate better what you want to do? I understand that each row is a vertex of your polygon and that the order implies the linestrings so first row connects with the second, second with third and so on. Last of the group would then connect with the first one?

Comment: The first polygon should be:

-3.6449779397   40.4307339003\n

-3.64510182294  40.4307061424\n

-3.64534323472  40.4306011803\n

-3.64558445341  40.4304737628\n

-3.64582154951  40.4303417733\n

-3.64594391235  40.4302735093\n

with intensity 32721.5 (of the color)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks like a combination of:

- Create point geometries from coordinates
- Aggregate by the `id`, but you lack an ordering field.
- Assuming you can group and order your points then you can [create a line](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_MakeLine.html), and then [a polygon](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_BuildArea.html).

Of course, all this need to be made with SQL and PostGIS functions. Alternatively, you can break the process in two parts, with CARTO BUILDER you can you can get the lines but there is not an analysis for building areas so you should need to save them as a new table and then create the polygons with `ST_BuildArea` or `ST_MakePolygon`.